# Scala/Slick - JSON writers for case class used to map slick tables

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have a case class and I use that in extending Table class.

```
case class Foo (
  ..
)

class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "foo") {
  ..
  override def * = (...) <> (Foo.tupled, Foo.unapply)
}
```

All works find. Now I want to define a JSON writer for this case class too.

```
object Foo {
  implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] = (
    ...
  )(unlift(Foo.unapply))
}
```

Above code will result in an error that conflicts with star projection in the table definition -- something like "value tupled is not a member of object models.Foo". So I ended up creating a new case class FooDuplicate and ended up duplicating all members of Foo and use that for JSON encoding/decoding. As I understand there is no inheritance with case class.

Is there a way to avoid duplicating the members of the case class in the above scenario? I believe containing one case class inside other will not help either as I cannot define a JSON writer for the contained case class for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding the problem, I had a similar problem. I fixed with:

```
def * = (...) <>((Foo.apply _).tupled, Foo.unapply)
```

it is not pretty, but it works. At the time I googled to understand the problem, but I can't remember the justification. But has something to do with the companion object and the things it creates automatically.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.. Thanks so much